# Websauna threading runtime signal error with pdb.set_trace()

Tags: pyramid, pylons, websauna

I want to debug the runtime of a websauna app, so I set a

pdb.set_trace()

in

system/admin/views.py:87 like so,

```
@view_config(context=ModelAdmin.Resource, name="show", renderer="crud/show.html", route_name="admin", permission='view')
def show(self):
    # We override this method just to define admin route_name traversing
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    return super(Show, self).show()
```

but I get the pyramid runtime error:

```
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

How do I avoid getting this runtime error and just break on the set_trace() ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to provide the entire class containing this view? That error is not a result of the short snippet you have provided above.